# how to apply substring command to double percent variable in XP cmd scripts?

Tags: variables, command-line, batch-file, windows-xp

here is the example how you do it with normal variables:

```
SET _test=123456789abcdef0
SET _result=%_test:~-7%
ECHO %_result%
:: that shows: abcdef0
```

But what to do with variables with double percent at the begin (like `%%A`), variables like this are needed in for loops:

```
FOR /D %%d IN (c:\windows\*) DO (
  echo %%d
)
```

this works, but:

```
FOR /D %%d IN (c:\windows\*) DO (
  echo %%d:~-7%
)
```

simply copies `:~-7` into the echo command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replace and substring syntax only works for variables not for parameters.

But you can simply copy the parameter into a variable and then use the substring syntax.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /D %%d IN (c:\windows\*) DO (
  set "var=%%d"
  echo !var:~-7!
)
```

You need here the delayed expansion, as a normal %var% would be expanded while parsing the complete block, not at execution time.

Or you could use the `call` technic, but this is very slow and have many side effects.

```
FOR /D %%d IN (c:\windows\*) DO (
  set "var=%%d"
  call echo %%var:~-7%%
)
```